# YUI dialog does not scroll

Tags: scroll, yui

I am using YUI Dialog.But vertical scrollbar does not apper even after doing 
overflow to auto.
It works fine if i give the height attribute while creating dialog

```
Here is the  code http://jsfiddle.net/SNfcG/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to dynamically set the height in order for it to get the scrollbar (so set height based on viewport size on page load, then reset it if the window is resized). I don't think that YUI2 panel does this out of the box for you.